# CYGWIN: why va_list is declared in wchar

Tags: c, windows, cygwin

In cygwin I stumbled on something weird (from my perspective).
va_list type is declared in wchar.h.
In linux and mingw it is declared elsewhere more explicit (vadefs.h for mingw for example).
Can anyone point out why this choice was made ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's _only_ declared there? I can understand why it's declared there though, probably for [`vwprintf` and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfwprintf). Maybe they didn't want to include any other header just for `va_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdarg.h is provided by the compiler:

```
$ cygcheck -l gcc-core | grep stdarg
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/cross-stdarg.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/stdarg.h
```

there is

```
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list
```